# Заменить по условию значение в одном столбце на значение из другого столбца одного DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, машинное-обучение, numpy

У меня есть следующий DataFarme

```
    Item    Store   Year    Week    Qnty_y  Date        is_season
 0  2178    5001    2017    43  0.0 2017-10-28             0
 1  2178    5001    2017    46  0.0 2017-11-19             0
 2  2178    5001    2017    47  1.0 2017-11-21             1
 3  2178    5001    2017    47  1.0 2017-11-24             1
 4  2178    5001    2017    47  1.0 2017-11-20             1
```

мне нужно получить следующий DataFrame

```
     Item   Store   Year    Week    Qnty_y  Date        is_season
 0  2178    5001    2017    43  0.0 2017-10-28             0
 1  2178    5001    2017    46  0.0 2017-11-19             0
 2  2178    5001    2017    47  1.0 2017-11-21     2017-11-21
 3  2178    5001    2017    47  1.0 2017-11-24             1
 4  2178    5001    2017    47  1.0 2017-11-20     2017-11-20
```

т.е. для каждого Item в поле is_season должна перенестись дата (Date) из той же строки, по условию первого вхождения единицы в поле is_season и последнего вхождения единицы в поле is_season

пробовала через

```
mask_1= df.eval('is_season == 1')
df.loc[mask_1, "Is_season"] \
= np.where(df.loc[mask_1].groupby("Item")['is_season'].first(), df.loc['Date'], 0)

df.loc[mask_1, "Is_season"] \
= np.where(df.loc[mask_1].groupby("Item")['is_season'].last(), df.loc['Date'], 0)
```

не помогает

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно сделать так:

```
idx = (df.query("is_season == 1")
         .index
         .to_series()
         .groupby(df["Item"])
         .agg(["first", "last"])
         .stack()
         .to_numpy())
df.loc[idx, "is_season"] = df.loc[idx, "Date"]
```

или так:

```
idx = (np.concatenate(df.query("is_season == 1")
                        .groupby("Item")
                        ["is_season"]
                        .apply(lambda x: x.index[[0,-1]].values)
         .values))
df.loc[idx, "is_season"] = df.loc[idx, "Date"]
```

---

результат:

```
In [74]: df
Out[74]:
   Item  Store  Year  Week  Qnty_y        Date   is_season
0  2178   5001  2017    43     0.0  2017-10-28           0
1  2178   5001  2017    46     0.0  2017-11-19           0
2  2178   5001  2017    47     1.0  2017-11-21  2017-11-21
3  2178   5001  2017    47     1.0  2017-11-24           1
4  2178   5001  2017    47     1.0  2017-11-20  2017-11-20
5  2222   5111  2017    43     0.0  2017-10-28           0
6  2222   5111  2017    47     1.0  2017-11-21  2017-11-21
7  2222   5111  2017    47     1.0  2017-11-20  2017-11-20
```